# What are the iPhone activities that change the height of the status bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, statusbar

What activities/events trigger the height of the status bar to change on the iPhone?

For example: When an application is visited while in a phone call the height of the status bar `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]` is 40 instead of it's normal height of 20.

The iOS Simulator has an option Hardware>Toggle In-Call Status Bar. When that is selected the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` are posted.

What user actions and/or phone actions cause this to happen? Are there any activities besides phone calls that cause the status bar to be taller than 20 pts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bogatyr is right, Internet tethering is one.

Audio recording (such as with the voicememos.app) is another.

Answer (score 2):

Internet tethering becoming active is another such activity.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the status bar ?in Application ?

Answer (score 0):

Also turn-by-turn navigation in a map app.

You'll see "Google Maps is Using Your Location" in the status bar when you use Google, and "Touch to return to Navigation" when you use Apple Maps.